# Is there a way to color the points in a Python seaborn pairplot with a quantitative value?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, visualization

When I use the seaborn library like this, `sns.pairplot(df, hue='number_value')`, it treats `number_value` as a categorical variable. From reading documentation it looks like `pairplot` doesn't have support for quantitative variables. Is this the case, or am I missing something?

If there is no support for this with `pairplot`, is there something else that works either in `seaborn` or `matplotlib` without requiring a for loop?

Here's an example of the legend generated when using the current approach:

[image: Example of legend with categorical coloring when it should be quantitative]

I don't want each value to be assigned a color, but to assign a color to each point based on a continuous scale from `min(df.hue)` to `max(df.hue)`.

Perhaps I am mistaken and `number_value` is being treated as quantitative and I simply need to remove the legend. But the plot takes a long time to generate.

`df` is a pandas DataFrame and `sns` is an alias for seaborn (`import seaborn as sns`).

Comment: It's hard to help if you don't provide your code and sample data. Please, provide a Minimal Reproducible Example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I will do so when I find time. For now, one could answer the primary question: Is there _a_ way? I suppose it is possible that the data is being treated as a string, but we'll address that later.

Comment: Sure this is possible, maybe with a combination of matplotlib scatter and Seaborn facetgid map dataframe https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html.

Comment: I've found that using seaborn.PairGrid() instead of seaborn.pairplot() solves the issue.
To get histograms along the diagonal, I can use `seaborn.PairGrid(df, hue = "number_value").map_diag(plt.hist).map_offdiag(plt.scatter)`, although the histogram looks wrong. Maybe it's trying to create individual histograms for each value.
https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.PairGrid.html

Comment: Amendment to my previous comment: Need to add .map(plt.scatter) when using seaborn.PairGrid() by itself: `seaborn.PairGrid(df, hue = 'number_value').map(plt.scatter)`